# Intellij IDEA 14(with JDK 8) on Mac Yosemite compiles project too long

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osx-yosemite, intellij-14

After I updated my Mac to Yosemite IntelliJ IDEA 14 started compiling project too long. I tried to compile a simple project with JDK 8 in Net Beans and it worked fast, but a simple one line project in IDEA compiles 20 minutes. It hangs on "Parsing java...". And here is the message in the Event log after compilation finished:

```
2:30:29 PM Compilation completed successfully with 2 warnings in 21m 39s 822ms
2:30:47 PM All files are up-to-date
```

I tried reinstalling Yosemite again, formatted the drive, installed all the software again and for some time it worked normally but then I installed updates in App Store, and this problem happened again. And I can't find anywhere on the internet any similar problem.

On Windows PC this project compiles in less than a minute.

Comment: Then this is a Mac issue, enjoy :(

Comment: [Report an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA), these problems are quite common  and can be fixed.

Comment: Wow, that sounds terrible. Have you tried compiling it in a terminal to see if the problem is with intellij or the jdk's compiler? You could try setting the project to use a different jdk and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me when I picked Eclipse compiler in Java compiler settings. Maybe not the best solution but at least now it works.